# Наполнение двумерного ассоциативного массива из двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Имеются две таблицы MySQL "places" как города и "bundesland" как области следующего вида:

```
PLACES
place_id place_name bundesland_id
1        hannover   5
2        münchen    7
3        wofsburg   5
4        laatzen    5
5        nürnberg   7

BUNDESLAND
bundesland_id bundesland_name
5             niedersachsen
7             bayern
```

Подскажите как образовать двумерный ассоциативный массив такого вида в PHP?

```
Array
    niedersachsen
        hannover
        wolfsburg
        laatzen
    bayern
        münchen
        nürnberg
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<db_name>;charset=UTF8;';
$opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, <user>, <password>, $opt);

$sql = 'SELECT b.bundesland_name, p.place_name FROM places AS p
  JOIN bundesland AS b
    ON p.bundesland_id = b.bundesland_id;';
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

print_r($data)
```

В результате получим что-то такое:

```
Array
(
    [niedersachsen] => Array
        (
            [0] => hannover
            [1] => wofsburg
            [2] => laatzen
        )

    [bayern] => Array
        (
            [0] => münchen
            [1] => nürnberg
        )

)
```

Comment: Поправил ответ, см. http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch#best

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-database/thread559961.html

---

код по ссылке:

```
mysql_select_db("zbase", $con);

     $sql = "SET NAMES 'cp1251'";
     mysql_query($sql);

$r=mysql_query ("SELECT sh.COLUMN_NAME, sh.table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns sh WHERE sh.TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT inf.table FROM zbase.info inf)AND table_schema =  'zbase'");


$table_name='';
$table_count=-1;
while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($r)) 
{
    if ($table_name!==$a[1])
    {
        $table_name=$a[1];
        $table_count++;
        $array[$table_count][0]=$table_name;
        $field_count=1;
    }
$array[$table_count][$field_count] = $a[0];
$field_count++;


}

print_r ($array);
```